# x86 SIGSEGV cuando escribo en el puerto paralelo

Tags: x86

Estoy ejecutando este código en x86:

```
mov ecx,0x4d 
mov edx,0x378 
mov eax,ecx 
out dx,al
in al,dx
```

Y en mi maquina no tengo puerto paralelo LTP1

¿Cómo puedo evitar la señal SIGSEGV cuando escribo o leo (out/in) en el puerto LTP1 (0X386)?

¿Hay alguna forma de simularlo?

Comment: Considera traducir al español de lo contrario puedes publicar dicha pregunta en Stackoverflow en Ingles.

Comment: virtualización o crear un network printer y mapear con net use (windows)